# React - API Call to set mutliple state variables (Better Alternatives)

Tags: react-hooks

I am learning react and during this process I was trying to set multiple state variables inside a single `useEffect` hook. I just wanted to know, if my approach is the right way to set multiple state variables. Please take a look and advice if there is a better approach.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const App = () => {
        const reqUrl = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux'
        const initialStateValue = [{ id: 0, value: ' --- Select A State --- ' }];

        const [initialJsonData, setInitialJsonData] = useState({ hits: [] });
        const [tagTypes, setTagTypes] = useState([]);
        const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState(initialStateValue[0].value);


        useEffect(() => {
            axios(reqUrl).then(result => {
                const tagTypeLocal = { ...result.data.hits[0] }
                setTagTypes(tagTypeLocal._tags) --> setting the state variable tagTypes
                console.log(tagTypeLocal._tags)
                setInitialJsonData(result.data) --> setting the state variable initialJsonData
            })

        }, [])
```

Comment: why do you want to set Mutliple states when all of them can be derived from the same result object

Comment: I added this project as an example to demonstrate why I need two setState. There is an author and tag dropdown. I wanted the author and the tag drop to be filled with corresponding data from API:

[codesandbox proj](https://6wpjnv68j3.codesandbox.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is an acceptable implementation for updating multiple state items with the `useEffect` hook.

And to address one of the comments to your question, it is more than fine to use multiple state variables as they might be updated at different times as suggested from the CodeSandbox you linked. In fact this approach is recommended in the [React docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)